# python update csv row via function

Tags: python, csv

Data:

`Rack,RU,MakeModel,status,hostname,type,lacp,,sw,swport,ip,mask,gw,vlan,
R01,01,dells4004,new,,,,sw01,eth1/1,,,,101`

Like to update specific row such as ip,mask,gw. How to update csv file with new data? 
I try copying the original file to temp, and then convert the data into list and loop each row. but I am unable to write to file.

```
        for i in data[1:]:
        if vlan == i[18]:
            ouput.writerow(i[12] = device)

    ouput.writerow(i[12] = device)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: Do `i[12]= device` and `output.writerow(i)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
ouput.writerow(i[12] = device)
```

If I understand what you're trying to do, you have to do it in two steps:  change the value in data, then write out the data line:

```
data[12] = device
ouput.writerow(data)
```